# Binary Search Tree insert() and removeMin()

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree

Here is my **BinaryTree.java :**

```
public abstract class BinaryTree<T> {

public BinaryTree<T> root = null;
//
public T key = null;
public BinaryTree<T> left = null;
public BinaryTree<T> right = null;

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return root == null;
}

public String toString() {
    return canonical();
}

public String canonical() {
    return canonical(root);
}

public String canonical(String comment) {
    System.out.println("______" + comment + "______");
    return canonical(root);
}

static final String ROOT_LEFT = "(";
static final String ROOT_RIGHT = ")";
static final String ROOT_SEP = "-";

public String canonical(BinaryTree<T> t) {
    if (t == null) {
        return ".";
    }
    String str = "";
    if (t.left != null) {
        str += canonical(t.left);
    }
    str += ROOT_SEP + t.key + ROOT_SEP;
    if (t.right != null) {
        str += canonical(t.right);
    }
    return ROOT_LEFT + str + ROOT_RIGHT;
}

public void treeView(String comment) {
    BinaryTreeView<T> btw = new BinaryTreeView<T>(comment, root, 400, 400);
    btw.refresh();
}


public void treePrint(String comment) {
    System.out.println("______" + comment + "______");
    if (isEmpty())
        System.out.println("Empty tree");
    else
        treePrint(root, 0);
}

protected void treePrint(BinaryTree<T> t, int depth) {
    String space = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
        space += "   ";
    }
    if (t != null) {
        int d = ++depth;
        treePrint(t.right, d);
        System.out.println(space + "/");
        System.out.print(space + "-");
        System.out.println(t.key);
        System.out.println(space + "\\");
        treePrint(t.left, d);
    } else {
        System.out.println(space + ".");
    }
}

// treeView
public int getHeight() {
    int lH = -1;
    int rH = -1;

    if (left != null) {
        lH = left.getHeight();
    }
    if (right != null) {
        rH = right.getHeight();
    }
    return Math.max(rH, lH) + 1;
}
}
```

And my **SearchTree.java:**

```
public class SearchTree extends BinaryTree<String> {

public SearchTree(String key) {
    this.key = key;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
    root = this;
}

public void insert(String key) {
// I need help for this part!
}

private void insert(BinaryTree<String> tree, String key) {
// I need help for this part!
}


 void removeMin() { // I am not sure if this is true!
 if (this.root.left == null) {
 root = root.right;
 } else
 removeMin(this.root.left, this.root);
 }

 void removeMin(BinaryTree<String> current, BinaryTree<String> previous) {
 if (current.left == null) {
 previous.left = current.right;
 return;
} else
 removeMin(current.left, current);
 }

}
```

Can you please help me with **insert()** and **removeMin()** methods in **SearchTree.java**?
I tried something in **removeMin()** method but I am not sure if it is correct.

And I have no idea how to insert a new node to this structure with **insert()** method.

**EDIT: TEST CASES**

```
TEST:   bst_insert_1
description:    Add 1-node tree
Correct:    (-b5-)
Yours:      (-b5-)
2   SUCCESS

TEST:   bst_insert_2
description:    Add 2-node tree, insert left
Correct:    ((-b4-)-b5-)
Yours:      (-b5-)
0   FAILED

TEST:   bst_insert_3
description:    Add 2-node tree, insert right
Correct:    (-b5-(-b6-))
Yours:      (-b5-)
0   FAILED

TEST:   bst_insert_4
description:    Add 2-node tree, insert right, left
Correct:    ((-b4-)-b5-(-b6-))
Yours:      (-b5-)
0   FAILED

TEST:   bst_insert_5
description:    Add 2-node tree, insert right, left, left-left
Correct:    (((-b2-)-b4-)-b5-(-b6-))
Yours:      (-b5-)
0   FAILED

TEST:   bst_insert_6
description:    Add to empty tree
Correct:    (-b4-)
Yours:      (-b5-)
0   FAILED

TEST:   bst_removeMin_1
description:    Remove 1-node tree, (-b5-)
Correct:    .
Yours:      (-b5-)
0   FAILED

TEST:   bst_removeMin_2
description:    Remove 2-node tree, ((-b4-)-b5-)
Correct:    (-b5-)
Yours:      (-b5-)
2   SUCCESS

TEST:   bst_removeMin_3
description:    Remove 2-node tree, (-b5-(-b6-))
Correct:    (-b6-)
Yours:      (-b5-)
0   FAILED

TEST:   bst_removeMin_4
description:    Remove 3-node tree, (-b5-((-b6-)-b7-))
Correct:    ((-b6-)-b7-)
Yours:      (-b5-)
0   FAILED

TEST:   bst_removeMin_5
description:    Remove 2-node tree, (-5-(-7-(-b-)))
Correct:    (-b7-(-b8-))
Yours:      (-b5-)
0   FAILED

TEST:   bst_removeMin_6
description:    Remove 2-node tree, (((-b2-)-b3-)-b5-)
Correct:    ((-b3-)-b5-)
Yours:      (-b5-)
0   FAILED

TEST:   bst_removeMin_7
description:    Remove 2-node tree,((-b3-(-b4-))-b5-)
Correct:    ((-b4-)-b5-)
Yours:      (-b5-)
0   FAILED
```

Comment: How is it possible that you have no idea? Have you read about the data structure? There is even a pseudo-code available at [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree).

Comment: For every node in the Binary-Tree `left.value < this.value < right.value`

Answer (score 0):

I will not give an answer for the `insert`. But a look at removeMin, which was correct as far as I saw, might help find a solution by using a "trick:"

The minimum is in the left-most child. If one works with recursion, you can use the function *result* instead of adding a *previous* parameter.
This simplifies understanding:

```
void removeMin() {
    root = removeMinSubtree(root);
}

/**
 * Post-condition: result is the same subtree, possibly minus
 * the minimum element when not empty.
 */
private BinaryTree<String> removeMinSubtree(BinaryTree<String> subtree) {
    if (subtree == null) {
        return null; // Cannot remove.
    } else if (subtree.left == null) {
        return right; // Remove left-most child.
    } else {
        subtree.left = removeMin(subtree.left);
        return subtree;
    }
}
```

Less cases, easier to see the invariant condition `left < value < right` being maintained.

For `insert` you might like to use a return value as well, instead of a parameter.

BTW. `class BinaryTree<T extends Comparable<T>>` so one can use `compareTo` would be for a general solution with value comparison.